# Why are Active Forum Topics and New Forum Topics visible only to Administrator?

Tags: nodes, users

I have set up forums in Drupal 7 with the [Forum Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/forum_access) module enabled and the Active Forum Topics block and the New Forum Topics block enabled on the home page. Everything works as it should except that those two blocks show content only to the Administrator user. The titles of the blocks appear to other users, but no content under the titles. Authenticated users are able to view and add content to the forums directly, but these two blocks on the home page show them nothing. I have looked high and low, rebuilt permissions, and tried changing many different permissions, but I have not been able to fix this problem. Any suggestions, insights, fixes?

OK. So I returned to my site after about 8 hours and the two blocks now show the new forum topic to everyone. After a little more experimentation, it appears that cron must be run to make new topics visible to anyone besides the administrator or to stop showing topics that have been deleted to everyone including the administrator.

Comment: If you are sure that your setup is correct, try to clone the site to a dev environment and start disabling/removing other parts of the site (e.g. modules, un-doing configuration etc.). You should come to the point where the blocks start displaying properly again - the last thing you changed probably caused the issue. If this will take more time, try creating a clean installation and reproduce the issue first.